# PhpSpreadsheet how to keep richtext inside html table

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I use PhpSpreadsheet top convert an html table to Excel file.

It work great but if inside a table cell i've mixed text formatting, i lose it.

For example if in a table td cell i i've:

```
...
<td>
   Hi mi name is <strong>SAM</strong> and i feel good
</td>
...
```

When I convert it to excel file, my excel file has cell like this:

```
Hi mi name isSAMand i feel good
```

(bold is lost and whitespace before and after SAM gone)

I'd like to keep "strong" and other html attributes.

My code:

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html();
$spreadsheet = $reader->loadFromString($table_html);
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="export.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: I can't replicate the issue using phpspreadsheet 1.17.1 and Excel O365. Could you provide what version of each you're using?